# CSS: 2 columns layout without <table> and with first column variable height

Tags: css, layout, css-float

I would like:

1. To design a 2-column layout: 1 fixed width (say 200px) and the other one using all the remaining width room
2. The first one height is variable and unknown, and I don't want it outside its parent flow

Before using CSS, I would have simply used a `<table>` with two `<td>` to do that.
With CSS, and for now, I use an approach based on float left column + left-padded right column + clear both `<div>` after:

```
.container2 .columnLeft {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}

.container2 .columnRight {
  padding-left: 200px;
}
```

But I am not sure this is a correct approach.
Could you tell me how you would do it please ?

Please use and modify http://jsfiddle.net/rjjr24sf/4/ at your convenience.

Thanks,

Comment: Seems like you didn't like any of the proposed solutions - didn't it solve your issue? Is it not what you're after?

Comment: I had already a solution for that, and was wondering for others' solutions. Unfortunately, I cannot mark answers as useful since I don't have enough reputation, but it helps, definitely! Thanks

Comment: No worries. You can always accept an answer, but there is no "one and only valid" answer to your question, as there are many ways to achieve this type of layout. All usually depends on the other factors, like browsers you need to support etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `display` CSS property to make your `divs` behave like table cells. This is done by setting `display: table;` on the parent, and `display: table-cell;` on the children.

Try this code:

```
.container {
   display: table;
}

.container .columnLeft {
    width: 200px;
    display: table-cell;
}

.container .columnRight {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

The only difference using this method is that your first fixed column will take up the same height as it's parent, the same as a `td` would. Although, you can fix this by adding `float: left;` onto your children.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rjjr24sf/5/)**

Answer (score 1):

Using flexbox:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
}
.container .columnLeft {
    width: 200px;
}
.container .columnRight {
    flex: 1; /* Grow to rest of width */
}
```

Comment: May be worth noting that this method is not fully supported in all browsers, such as IE 7-9 or Opera Mini 8: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: @Andy Thanks for letting me discover the CanIUse website (with robjez also)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/bgBXM/10/

```
#RightColumn {
margin-left: 200px;
background-color: blue;
}

#LeftColumn {
float : left;
width: 200px;
background-color: red
}

<div id="Container">
<div id="LeftColumn">Left column</div>
<div id="RightColumn">Right column</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is basically what I use, but you need to clear both directions after also with a <div style="clear:both"> so that the container has the good height

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CSS calc method to achieve that, as per this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/aewqgh7t/
so markup:

```
<div class="container2">
    <div class="columnLeft">
        Some Content<br/>
        Some Content<br/>
        Some Content<br/>
        Some Content<br/>
        Some Content
    </div>
    <div class="columnRight">
        Some Content
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container2 { 
   width:100%; 
   background: lightgrey; 
   overflow:hidden; 
}
.columnLeft { 
   background: salmon; 
   float:left; 
   width:200px; 
}
.columnRight { 
   background: darkblue; 
   float:left; 
   margin-left:20px; 
   width: calc(100% - 220px) /* To calculate remaining space */; 
}
```

You also need to consider browser support for calc css function: [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

Comment: Thanks for letting me discover the CanIUse website.

Comment: No worries mate - just one note to add. this method doesn't care about your child elements height, because of `overflow: hidden` rule. both columns will stay next to each other (for calc() function supporting browsers), no matter the amount of content they hold or their height